Unwanted left indent / margin in struktex / struktogram
all my struktograms in struktex have an unwanted indent/margin at the left. I don't know why - can U help me out?
I experienced with some options: outer, parskip - nothing helps.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[outer]{struktex}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\sffamily%
\begin{struktogramm}(170,42)%
\assign{Drücke im Viewsonic-Homescreen auf die Uhrzeit}
\ifthenelse{5}{5}{Steht unter 'vom Netzwerk bereitgestellte Zeit' schon die richtige Uhrzeit?}{ja}{nein}
\assign[20]{Stelle Zeitzone auf 'GMT$+$0'}
\change
\assign[20]{Stelle Zeitzone entsprechend ein, GMT$-$1 oder GMT$+$1}
\ifend
\end{struktogramm}
\end{document}



with \hspace*{-7mm} i get rid of that space but that is odd a bit

One workaround is to append optional varwidth with large width, e.g. 20cm. The whole content of document will then be wrapped by varwidth environment. See documentation of standalone and varwidth for more info.

The problem is in struktex.sty which has
\def\struktogramm@NoProof(#1,#2)[#3]{%
    \def\next{#3}
    \setlength{\savelength@nss}{\unitlength}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.001mm}
    \begin{minipage}[\Position@nss]{#1mm}
        \ifx\next\empty\else #3\\[\smallskipamount]\fi%
        \begin{picture}(#1000,#2000)%
            \str@kt{0}{#2000}{#1000}%
}

and this inserts three unwanted space tokens.
File a bug report. The correct code should be
\def\struktogramm@NoProof(#1,#2)[#3]{%
    \def\next{#3}%
    \setlength{\savelength@nss}{\unitlength}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.001mm}%
    \begin{minipage}[\Position@nss]{#1mm}
        \ifx\next\empty\else #3\\[\smallskipamount]\fi
        \begin{picture}(#1000,#2000)
            \str@kt{0}{#2000}{#1000}
}

You can see the differences: I added three % characters (and removed three that do nothing, but were actually harmless).
What happens is that if you use struktogramm in a normal document, you probably will have it between paragraphs, so those spaces aren't significant. But standalone typesets its input inside \mbox and now those spaces become signifiicant.
Workaround:
\documentclass[12pt, border=2pt,varwidth=1000pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[outer]{struktex}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{struktogramm}(170,42)
\assign{Drücke im Viewsonic-Homescreen auf die Uhrzeit}
\ifthenelse{5}{5}{Steht unter 'vom Netzwerk bereitgestellte Zeit'
   schon die richtige Uhrzeit?}{ja}{nein}
\assign[20]{Stelle Zeitzone auf 'GMT$+$0'}
\change
\assign[20]{Stelle Zeitzone entsprechend ein, GMT$-$1 oder GMT$+$1}
\ifend
\end{struktogramm}

\end{document}

In any case using parskip and setting \parindent should be avoided in standalone.

thanks to all responders! i accepted this answer cause this delivers a root cause a solution and a workaround. THANK YOU!

I've sent an email to the maintainer of struktex and mentioned you, egreg.

@texpiet You did well.
